# If Its empty, return something in PHP

Tags: php, is-empty

i have a code, it's getting data but when it gets nothing i want it to return something.

```
    $upcoming = simplexml_load_file('http://api.website.com'); 

foreach($upcoming->trailer as $x => $updates) {         
$content.= '<center><br><span> ' . $updates->embed . '</span></center>';
}
```

This is the code. It's getting data but when it got nothing, i would like it to say NO Videos.

How can i do that? I tried strlen() but i couldn't applied it.

I tried strpos but it didn't work either.

Comment: What do you mean by nothing? If `simplexml_load_file` fails it returns `FALSE`

Comment: Yeah when it returns FALSE, it showes nothing. But i want it to say something for example No Videos.

Comment: So `if ($upcoming === FALSE) $content .= 'no videos';` ?

Comment: it's not working, by the way it returns <trailers></trailers>

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check the result of simplexml_load_file and act accordingly

```
if (false === $upcoming) {
    echo "No Videos";
} else {
    //your foreach loop here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some flag in your foreach to put a flag if anything has been printed or just check the $upcoming.
Then just check the flag and echo "no videos" your message.

Do it like this:

```
$Something=false;
$upcoming = simplexml_load_file('http://api.website.com'); 

foreach($upcoming->trailer as $x => $updates) {
  if($updates->embed){
    $Something=true;
  }         
  $content.= '<center><br><span> ' . $updates->embed . '</span></center>';
}

if(!$Something){
  echo "<center>No videos</center>";
}
```

Or:

```
$upcoming = simplexml_load_file('http://api.website.com');

if(!$upcoming){
  echo "<center>No videos</center>";
}
else{
  foreach($upcoming->trailer as $x => $updates) {
    if($updates->embed){
      $Soemthing=true;
    }         
    $content.= '<center><br><span> ' . $updates->embed . '</span></center>';
  }
}
```

Comment: I am trying this but what if xml sending another text instead of false

Comment: i have edited answer, try now. both should work if $upcoming is empty.

Comment: if not working from above sample in my answer then try to put  print_r($upcoming);die("<br>END"); right after simplexml_load_file and see whats the output.

Comment: It still showes up with nothing. By the way i found what xml sends when its empty, it's sending "<trailers></trailers>"

Comment: well then edit the php which is doing the output you read @ http://api.website.com to return nothing or put if($upcoming=="<trailers></trailers>"){echo "No video";}else{//the foreach code}

Answer (score 0):

```
$upcoming = simplexml_load_file('http://api.website.com'); 
if($upcoming == null || $upcoming == false){
    $content = "No videos";
}
else{
    foreach($upcoming->trailer as $x => $updates) {         
    $content.= '<center><br><span> ' . $updates->embed . '</span></center>';
    }
}
```